# Query connections to broadcast only to certain users

Tags: asp.net, signalr

In my page I am setting up my connection like this:

```
var connection = $.connection("/notification-connection");
connection.received(function (data) {
    //whatever
});
connection.start({ items: [{ "ValidationTicket": ticket}] });
```

On the back end, how would I broadcast a notification to users whose ticket.ClientCode=XYZ? I know I can put users into groups but I also want to broadcast to users based on multiple criteria such as ticket.ClientCode=XYZ and ticket.UserName=JohnDoe, in that case groups would not really work.

Comment: I am pretty sure this is not supported by the API. You would have to do everything manually, adding people to groups, iterating over them and determining whether you send the message or not, based on the extra conditions.

Comment: So keep track of connection ids in my own collection so that I can query that, then broadcast with every connection id excluded that doesnt match?

Comment: If creating groups for all the possible conditions that you may encounter is not practical/feasible, then yes, I am pretty sure you have to manage everything manually. Just remember that one user can belong to many groups at the same time...

Answer (score 0):

Just in case anyone is looking around for a similar solution I am going to end up with something like this:

```
public class NotificationConnection : PersistentConnection
{
    public NotificationConnection()
    {
        if (Clients == null)
            Clients = new ConcurrentDictionary<string, IRequest>();
    }

    public static ConcurrentDictionary<string, IRequest> Clients { get; private set; }

    protected override Task OnConnected(IRequest request, string connectionId)
    {
        Clients.TryAdd(connectionId, request);
        return base.OnConnected(request, connectionId);
    }

    protected override Task OnDisconnected(IRequest request, string connectionId)
    {
        IRequest outRequest;
        Clients.TryRemove(connectionId, out outRequest);
        return base.OnDisconnected(request, connectionId);
    }
}
```

Then I can broadcast to the connections I want like this:

```
public void SendNotification(Notification notification)
{
    if(notification == null)
        throw new ArgumentNullException("notification");

    //...

    var excludedConnectionIds = NotificationConnection.Clients.Where(x => x.Value.Items.Values.Cast<ValidationTicket>().Any(y => y == null || y.UserKeyNames == null || y.ClientCode != notification.ClientCode || !y.UserKeyNames.Contains(notification.UserKeyName))).Select(x => x.Key);
    var context = GlobalHost.ConnectionManager.GetConnectionContext<NotificationConnection>();
    context.Connection.Broadcast(data, excludedConnectionIds.ToArray());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The above code sample is a good way to manage users and groups, but if you want your groups list to survive a server reboot or application pool recycle, you can't store the group information in memory-you'll need to persist to file or database instead.